# how to add icon in image on button

Tags: flutter

```
MaterialButton(

            height: _height/11,
            minWidth: _width/1.2,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(12)),
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text(
              
              "Login",
              style: TextStyle(
fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,fontSize: _large? 40 : (_medium? 24 : 24),fontFamily:'Roboto',
color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Can you add an image the thing you like to archive with code, and explain a little more what is going wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an icon to your button beside the text, just use
`ElevatedButton.icon()`
If you want to have just an icon and no text, then make the `child`of the button an `Icon` widget.